# How to make multiple Alamofire requests with operation query

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsoperationqueue

I have an app that uploads multiple images to the server using *Alamofire*. Each image needs an upload token before uploading to the server. So, in a for loop, for every image file,

> 1. I make a get request via Alamofire to get the upload token
> 2. After getting the token, I make an upload request via Alamofire, with that token.

Here is my code:

```
func uploadFile(image: imageToUpload, onCompletion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {

   ...//some code
       
   // Alamofire request to get an upload token
   getUploadToken() { uploadToken in 
     
   if uploadToken != nil {
       // Alamofire request to make the upload with uploadToken and image data
       makeUploadRequest(token: uploadToken, image: imageToUpload) { uploadResponse in 
              onCompletion(uploadResponse)
       }
   }
}
```

And this is my for loop to iterate through the images to upload:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for fileToUpload in filesToUpload {
        group.enter()
        FileOperations.shared.uploadFile(image: fileToUpload) { hasFinished in
            if hasFinished {
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        group.wait()
    }
}
```

So I need to use queues to implement this. My code needs to work like this:

> 1. Queue 1: getUploadToken request for image 1.
> 2. Queue 2: makeUploadRequest for image 1.
> 3. Queue 3: getUploadToken request for image 2.
> 4. Queue 4: makeUploadRequest for image 2.
>
> ... and so on.

So only after image 1 in for loop completes its whole process, the image 2 can start its process. With queues, even if the app is backgrounded, it should work.

How can I achieve this kind of behaviour with queues?

I can make this work with `DispatchGroup()`, but it doesn't work when the app backgrounded. I researched and read everything on the internet but I couldn't get anything seem to work. So I want to make this work with queues. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can do this with an `OperationQueue` all you'll need to do is subclass `Operation` to get it configured to perform the actions you want and initialize an `OperationQueue` and configure that to run on a background thread and only allow one concurrent task. Then, add the operations to the queue in the order you want and they will begin executing.

Comment: Thanks, I configured an OperationQueue like you said but I couldn't add my operations to this queue. Can you give me an example?

Comment: You need to subclass the default implementation of `Operation` to create your own asynchronous operation. How to do that is outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation). Once you've followed those instructions to make a subclass, instantiate one of your new subclasses and add it to the operation queue using the `.add()` function.

Comment: I am also not sure that this will help with making the operation continue when your app is backgrounded or killed. You should also take a look at [Apple's documentation on background execution in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code to the following and check if for example three images are uploaded correctly.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    for fileToUpload in filesToUpload {
        group.enter()
        FileOperations.shared.uploadFile(image: fileToUpload) { hasFinished in
            if hasFinished {
                group.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Finished all upload requests.")
}
```